# Query for an integer array from PostreSQL always returns []uint8

Tags: go, pq

Take a simple PostreSQL db with an integer array:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id                       serial PRIMARY KEY,
    bar               integer[]
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES(DEFAULT, '{1234567, 20, 30, 40}');
```

Using pq, these values are for some reason being retrieved as an array of []uint8.
The [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Data_Types) says that integer types are returned as int64. Does this not apply to arrays as well?

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=a_user password=your_pwd dbname=blah")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

var ret []int
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE id=$1", 1).Scan(&ret)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(ret)
```

Output:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 0: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]int64
[]
```

Comment: You're using `[]int`, but the error says `*[]int64`. Are you sure your code matches your error message?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use a slice of int as a `driver.Value`. The arguments to `Scan` *must* be of one of the [supported types](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Value), or implement the [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface.

The reason you're seeing `[]uint8` in the error message is that the raw value returned from the database is a `[]byte` slice, for which `[]uint8` is a synonym.

To interpret that `[]byte` slice appropriately as a custom PostgreSQL array type, you should use the appropriate array types defined in the [pq](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) package, such as the [Int64Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Int64Array).

Try something like this:

```
var ret pq.Int64Array
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE id=$1", 1).Scan(&ret)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be more severe if you use fetching multiple rows.
The above code works for a single row, to fetch multiple rows use like this

`rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, stmt, courseCode)
if err != nil {
return nil, err
}
defer rows.Close()

```
var feedbacks []*Feedback1

for rows.Next() {
    var feedback Feedback1
    var ret pq.Int64Array
    var ret1 pq.Int64Array
    err := rows.Scan(
        &feedback.ID,
        &ret,
        &ret1,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    //for loop to convert int64 to int
    for i:=0;i<len(ret);i++{
        feedback.UnitFeedback = append(feedback.UnitFeedback,int(ret[i]))}

    for i:=0;i<len(ret1);i++{
        feedback.GeneralFeedback = append(feedback.GeneralFeedback,int(ret1[i]))}

    feedbacks = append(feedbacks, &feedback)
}`
```